Roll Up with column changes
Table below - order by [low],[high]



Group
Section
Low
High




A
01
01
10


A
01
11
15


A
01
18
18


A
01
19
25


A
02
26
30


A
02
31
32


A
01
33
40


A
01
41
41



By using the table above, I would like to create another table (the example below), so every time before the [Section] change, I would like the get the MIN(Low) and MAX(High).



Group
Section
Low
High




A
01
01
25


A
02
26
32


A
01
33
41



Obviously, this is too simple and would not work
select [group], [section], min([low]), max([high])
from table
group by [group], [section]


Have you tried anything? Can you show us?

What is the ordering column to detect  the [Section] change, Low probably? Just a guess, specify it explicitly.

Sounds like a [[tag:gaps-and-islands]] problem; there are plenty of examples if you have a look at that tag.

You could also find the different groups by partitioning those with various combinations and finding their difference.
;WITH GroupedData AS (
    SELECT 
        GroupName,
        Section,
        [Low],
        [High],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY [Low]) 
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupName, Section ORDER BY [Low]) AS GroupingKey
    FROM DataTable
)
--select * from GroupedData;
SELECT 
    GroupName,
    Section,
    MIN([Low]) AS [Low],
    MAX([High]) AS [High]
FROM GroupedData
GROUP BY GroupName, Section, GroupingKey
ORDER BY 1, 3;

Result Grid:


This is called gaps and islands, where you want to group things until a change.
I usually go for this three-stage solution:
;WITH data AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES (N'A', N'01', N'01', 10)
        ,   (N'A', N'01', N'11', 15)
        ,   (N'A', N'01', N'18', 18)
        ,   (N'A', N'01', N'19', 25)
        ,   (N'A', N'02', N'26', 30)
        ,   (N'A', N'02', N'31', 32)
        ,   (N'A', N'01', N'33', 40)
        ,   (N'A', N'01', N'41', 41)
    ) t ([Group],Section,Low,High)
)
SELECT  grouping, [group], MIN(Low) AS minLow, MAX(high) AS maxHigh /* 3 */
FROM    (
    SELECT  COUNT(flag) OVER(partition BY [group] ORDER BY low ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS grouping /* 2 */
    ,   *
    FROM    (
            SELECT  CASE WHEN LAG(section) OVER(partition BY [group] ORDER BY low) <> section THEN 1 END AS flag /* 1 */
            ,   *
            FROM    data
        ) x
    ) x
GROUP BY [group], grouping


You create a flag which says if previous value is not the same as current, every time this flags turns to 1, it's a start of a new group.
Count or summarize the flag using a ordered window function. This creates the final grouping. The rows unbounded preceding is mostly Sql Server goo which improves performance of the window aggregate
Now, you're ready to actually perform the aggregation based on our new grouping column, it's a simple GROUP BY.

The output:



grouping
group
minLow
maxHigh




0
A
01
25


1
A
26
32


2
A
33
41



PS: watch out for the low/high values, since you use 01 they might not be real integers but varchars, then you have to make sure they're all padded to same length, because a varchar 99 is more than 100
